# Frobenius Method for r = 1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

The general methodology for this involves assuming a solution of the form $$ y = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{n+r}.$$

One normally keeps the index $0$ for the first and second derivatives. My question regards the case where $r=1$ in which case $$y' = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)a_nx^n $$ Which of the following is correct for $y''$?

$$y''=  \sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n+1)a_nx^{n-1}$$   OR

$$y''=  \sum_{n=1}^\infty n(n+1)a_nx^{n-1}$$

Classically the index would be incremented to $n=1$ but the indicial equation is only popping up in front of $a_0$ when I keep the index $0$. I haven't seen the existence theorem for this I'm wondering if maybe this is supposed to be considered a Laurent series with all the negative coefficients $0$

Comment: This doesn't really have much to do with infinite series, it's just understanding derivatives of arbitrary polynomials. If you take two derivatives of $\sum_{i=0}^N a_i x^i$ you get $\sum_{i=0}^N i(i-1) a_i x^{i-2}$. Now the first two terms vanish so you can shift the indices to get $\sum_{i=0}^{N-2} a_{i+2} x^i$. If perhaps the first few coefficients are zero, instead of messing with shifting indices, just set those coefficients to be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure why you have an $r$ in your equation, as forces $y(0)$ to be $0$ since there is no constant term. So I will explain how the Frobenius method works. When using the Frobenius method, we simply assume the solution is analytic, which means that we can express it as
$$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$$
The constant term then drops out when we take the derivative term by term to get
$$y' = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}x^n$$
Then taking the derivative again, the constant term drops out again and we get
$$y'' = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n+1)(n)a_{n+1}x^{{n-1}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^{n}$$
And in general
$$y^{(m)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigg(\prod_{i=1}^{m}(n+i)\bigg) a_{n+m}x^n$$
So onto your question, your two sums are equivalent as the first term of your sum is simply $0$, as it was a constant which was differentiated.
Hoepfully this helps!

Comment: gotcha. The r was the root of the indicial equation. Was causing problems with the grouping but I've got it squared now. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.